# sinon spy on standalone function

Tags: sinon

When I use Sinon on a function inside an object, it works:

```
function myFunc() {
    console.log('hello');
}
var myObj = { myFunc: myFunc };
var spy = sinon.stub(myFunc);
myObj.myFunc();
expect(spy.called).to.be.true();
```

However, I don't know why when I use Sinon on a standalone function as follow:

```
function myFunc() {
    console.log('hello');
}
var spy = sinon.stub(myFunc);
myFunc();
expect(spy.called).to.be.true();
```

the assertion fails.

Comment: i also run into the same issue, is there any update on this topic ?

Comment: Still not working when spying a standalone function

Answer (score 26):

You were *kinda* on the right path but deviated. Let's walk through your effort and get things right:

```js
// ...
function myFunc() {
    console.log( 'hello' );
}
var spiedMyFunc = sinon.spy( myFunc ); // what you want is a 'spy' not a 'stub'
// ...
```

Then at this point `spiedMyFunc` wraps `myFunc`. Hence, calling `spiedMyFunc()` should mostly ***amount to*** the same outcome as calling `myFunc()`. Meanwhile `spiedMyFunc` additionally

> records arguments, this value, exceptions and return values for all
> calls.

So the rest of the code snippet should go as follows:

```js
// myFunc(); // no you should be calling spiedMyFunc() instead
spiedMyFunc();
expect( spiedMyFunc.called ).to.be.true();
```

And that is how you spy on a *standalone* function. However, **it does not make conceptual sense to stub a *standalone* function**.

---

Answer to [@charlesdeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771657/charlesdeb)'s question in a comment on this answer:

When a method is called, it can trigger a chain that implicitly calls other methods. Due to this implicit or indirect calls, you may want to *control how other methods in the chain behave* while *studying* the behaviour of a particular method. **Stubbing** is a means for realising the said control.

When working with functions it is beneficial to actually follow the functional paradigm to make things easy and reliable. Consider this:

```js
function a () { ... }

function b () { a(); }
```

When testing `b`, it is necessary and sufficient to prove that the execution of `b()` in turn executed `a()`. But with the way `b` was implemented, it is impossible to verify that `a` was called.

However, if we applied the functional paradigm then we should have

```js
function a () { ... }

function b ( a ) { a(); }
```

Consequently we can write a simple test as follows:

```js
var a_spy = sinon.spy( a );

var actualOutcomeOfCallingB = b( a_spy );

expect( a_spy.called ).to.be.true;
expect( actualOutcomeOfCallingB ).to.equal( expectedOutcome );
```

If you'd like to *stub* `a`, then instead of creating a spy with the real `a` do so with your preferred stub.

```js
var a_stub = sinon.spy( function () { /* behaves differently than the actual `a` */ }  ); // that's your stub right there!

var actualOutcomeOfCallingB = b( a_stub );

expect( a_stub.called ).to.be.true;
expect( actualOutcomeOfCallingB ).to.equal( expectedOutcome );
```

Comment: thanks for tidying up the logic for the OP. I follow the first code block, but at the end you say: "It does not make conceptual sense to stub a standalone function." Why not? Not all of the functions in my code belong to objects. Some really are standalone, and I want to test them without having to attach them to some hold-all object. I really want to see if myFunc() is getting called in the code under test. spiedMyFunc() does not exist in my source - and of course never gets called.

Comment: @charlesdeb, I have responded to your question by editing my answer. Check my updated answer..

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. You say that unless you apply the functional paradigm and call 'a' as one of the arguments in 'b', then " it is impossible to verify that a was called". Is this just some kind of sinon limitation on standalone functions? I would have thought that after setting up 'a_spy', then regardless of where and how 'a' was called, I can test those calls by checking 'a_spy'. It seems to do that for non-standalone functions. Maybe I am missing somethng here!

Comment: I have an idea for a way to conclusively clarify the matter for you: how about you create a hypothetical source code that should be tested and build your questions around it, and we can both analyse the challenge together?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether there is solution on browser side.

But if you run it in node.js environment, you can export the function and test it in another file.

For example, your source file is `source.js` and the test file is `test.js`

In source.js

```
function myFunc() {
    console.log('hello');
}
module.exports.myFunc = myFunc;
```

In test.js

```
var source = require('./source');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

sinon.stub(source, 'myFunc').returns(true);
source.myFunc();
expect(sinon).to.be.true;
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: The code above does not work in most situations. Sinon cannot stub standalone functions. What you're really doing is exporting an function as an object. See this from Sinon: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/664

Comment: I was running into a problem where I used imports instead of requires, and I was not able to stub. When I used require instead of import as seen in this answer it worked.

Also, if you are dealing with default export of a function, then you again want to use require instead of import, and you also will need to stub against the function name "default" rather than the actual function name.

const myexportedfunction = require('./source');

let mystub = sinon.stub(myexportedfunction, "default");

Answer (score 0):

Your first example does not work as well. It is currently not possible to create stub from standalone function. You can stub object's method:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(myObj, 'myFunc');
```

However if you want to spy on method or function, you should create a [spy](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies) (instead of stub):

Spy on method:

```
var spy = sinon.spy(myObj, 'myFunc');
myObj.myFunc(); // or spy();
expect(spy.called).to.be.true();
```

Spy on standalone function:

```
var spy = sinon.spy(myFunc); // returns spied function
spy();
expect(spyFunc.called).to.be.true();
```

Notice that `sinon.spy(myFunc)` does not modify original function it just returns a spy.

Comment: This is actually pretty bad answer because OP obviously does not want to use sinon's spy. OP wants to SPY ON the standalone function. Sinon spy() creates function. It does not spy on another function.